# Need some ideas about a workflow design

Tags: .net, workflow, workflow-foundation-4, state-machine

I want to start building a technical support application as a personal project, using Windows Workflow Foundation 4 for implementing the business process.I'm very new to WF and BPs but that's why i am doing this. Did some research and I found that a state machine workflow will be best suited for this as it is a long running process with lots of human intervention. So basically the flow I thought of will be like this:

- user submits a form with all the
  required data.
- a Ticket object is created and passed
  in as an InArgument for the workflow.
  The ticket is now in the Pending
  state and waits for a ResumeBookmark
  call when a admin opens the ticket.
- the admin assigns (meaning that some
  of the object properties will be
  initialized/modified/etc and also
  some db tables) the ticket to a
  engineer and it goes into a Assigned
  state. And so on..

  Now my problem is: I can't figure out a way to add some level of complexity of the State activity flow other than modifying the object properties. By complexity I mean a way to make use of this technology, because for now i don't see the upside of this compared to a  imperative implementation. 
  any ideas are well received .thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, I'd recommend picking up the book [Pro WF: Windows Workflow in .NET 4.0](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430227214) and working through the tutorials (if you haven't yet). While it's not perfect, it covers many of the important topics.

For a long-running process you're almost certainly going to want to implement persistence. Otherwise if your server goes down, running workflows disappear. Also consider hosting under IIS.

Subscribe to [The Problem Solver](http://msmvps.com/blogs/theproblemsolver/default.aspx) and check out [his answers on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19676/maurice). He also has an [Introduction to WF 4 video series](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/dd733248). There are several videos by others on [Channel 9](http://channel9.msdn.com), too.

[State Machine](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee264171.aspx) doesn't come out of the box; it's a separate download. It's not required, though - you could use Sequential, Flowchart, or a combination to achieve what you want.

Be prepared to write custom activities. (See the Channel 9 videos, especially Leon Welicki's.) You'll have to implement security, locking, worklists, etc. if those are part of your requirements. WF is not a [BPM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Business_process_modeling) system out of the box.

Finally, don't be intimidated. This is all doable, and WF 4 is a well-thought-out framework. Just be prepared to spend considerable time learning and implementing this.

Answer (score 0):

I found this worked example useful for hosting a WF4 service under WCF. It also covers a number of key concepts you can explore further:

http://programming4.us/Enterprise/332.aspx